# Facebook server-side login error for one subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have successfully implemented a login route for logging in using Facebook.

- http://[sub.]example.com/fb/login
- http://[sub.]example.com/fb/login_callback

This works under any subdomain. However recently I found out that this does not work for my `m.buy` subdomain. When calling the login, my browser will display the following message:

> SECURITY WARNING: Sharing the above URL with anyone is the same as sharing your Facebook password with them - it will give them access to your Facebook account. Despite what you may have been promised, you will not receive cash, a gift card, or free airline tickets in exchange for this URL.

Here is the network trace of login error:
[image: error login]

Here is the network trace of a successful login using another subdomain:
[image: successful login]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the particular subdomain is considered as spam by Facebook. Someone probably reported it. I am currently [writing a physical letter to Facebook](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24997/website-falsely-blocked-because-of-spam-does-anyone-know-how-we-should-proceed) according to this answer. Will update if it works.